# How can I simply filter a 3d numpy array by its 1st column values?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Suppose I have a 3D numpy array like this:

```
 data = np.array([[[1,2,3,4],[1,2.5,3,5]],
                 [[116,230,450,430],[80,100,300,320]],
                 [[60,100,120,80],[50,80,100,90]]])
```

How can I simply extract from it a 3D numpy array of same shape with a condition on axis 0, for example selecting those "rows" for which axis 0 < 3? A naïve way would be

```
data[data[0]<3]
```

But this fails:

IndexError: boolean index did not match indexed array along dimension 0; dimension is 3 but corresponding boolean dimension is 2

Comment: You need to be more specific here, a row contains more than one number, so you should specify whether you want any number less than 3, all numbers less than 3, or something else such as the sum of numbers less than 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See my comment above, but from your data I am guessing you want the rows with any values less than 3. If so you could do:

```
data[(data<3).any(axis=2)]
>>> array([[1. , 2. , 3. , 4. ],
           [1. , 2.5, 3. , 5. ]])
```

EDIT1:

Solution can be achieved using transposition to match up the axis dimensions:

```
data.T[(data[0]<3).any(axis=0).T].T
>>> array([[[  1. ,   2. ],
            [  1. ,   2.5]],

           [[116. , 230. ],
            [ 80. , 100. ]],

           [[ 60. , 100. ],
            [ 50. ,  80. ]]])
```

EDIT2:

Another method that does not involve transposing. To apply the mask `(data[0]<3).any(axis=0)` onto the original data array the axes shapes must match. The shape of the mask is `(4,)` and `data.shape = (3, 2, 4)`, so we need to apply the mask to the last axis as:

```
data[..., (data[0]<3).any(axis=0)]
>>> array([[[  1. ,   2. ],
            [  1. ,   2.5]],

           [[116. , 230. ],
            [ 80. , 100. ]],

           [[ 60. , 100. ],
            [ 50. ,  80. ]]])
```

Comment: I wasn't clear enough. By selecting axis 0 to be < 3, I meant that I would obtain `dataNew = np.array([[[1,2],[1,2.5]],
                 [[116,230],[80,100]],
                 [[60,100],[50,80]]])`

Comment: Okay, I've made an edit to my answer, I hope it helps

Comment: Is the transpose in index array (inside brackets) necessary?

Comment: I've made another edit which doesn't involve transposing. The trick to using a mask is that the mask shape must be the same as the array or axis you're applying it to, in this case it's the last axis.